# Removing unused references in ArcObjects vba?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, vba

Can anyone suggest me how will I find and remove unused references used in a project done in ArcGIS 9.3.1 vba.

Comment: Welcome GIS.SE forum. Could you please explain your question in detail? From where do you want to remove  reference (From Memory or some where else?)

Comment: Are you dealing with vb6? or VBA? It is not clear from your question, since you have tagged it VBA & have VB in the Question title and vb6 in the question body. And why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have a code that works fine with MS Excel Object Library 11 and 12. The machine with Office XP requires for Object Library 11 and machines iwth Office 2007 requires Object Lilbary 12. In my code, which is done in ArcGIS 9.3.1 using VBA, Microsoft Excel Object Library 12 is checked. But other machine withs XP shows missing reference when my tool is opened. I want to remove missing reference for example object library 12 for those machines and load Object library 11 and vice versa, but all using code, not manually.

Comment: You can just fix your one mxd and save the updated VBA configuration.  Then, just distribute the mxd file to all users.  Using code or manually updating each is not necessary.

Comment: @artwork21 This is an old question but perhaps you'd like to move your comment to an answer to get it off our Unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment noted, you can just fix your one mxd and save the updated VBA configuration within it. Then, just distribute the mxd file to all users. Using code or manually updating each is not necessary.